# Nextauth can't sign in with Apple

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

That's the log I get from Vercel. Facebook sign in works great but Apple - nope.
I setup my apple developer account, created apple secret and client keys. Add redirect url to Apple dev. acc. while setting up my app.

```
 [POST] /api/auth/callback/apple
    12:11:32:31
    2021-09-06T09:11:32.443Z    aa30bda1-4694-4b63-bb8d-adc0d3922d5e    ERROR   OAUTH_GET_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR [
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
          at exports.OAuth2.getOAuth2AccessToken [as getOAuthAccessToken] (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/lib/oauth/client.js:117:19)
          at oAuthCallback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/lib/oauth/callback.js:57:35)
          at Object.callback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/routes/callback.js:53:39)
          at /var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/index.js:240:27
          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5),
      'apple',
      'c8dd954aa497544239a68afd94bc16b30.0.rusw.eKwJZK8aNuWy7syp95O-OQ'
    ]
    2021-09-06T09:11:32.443Z    aa30bda1-4694-4b63-bb8d-adc0d3922d5e    ERROR   OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR [
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
          at exports.OAuth2.getOAuth2AccessToken [as getOAuthAccessToken] (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/lib/oauth/client.js:117:19)
          at oAuthCallback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/lib/oauth/callback.js:57:35)
          at Object.callback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/routes/callback.js:53:39)
          at /var/task/node_modules/next-auth/dist/server/index.js:240:27
          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    ]
    [POST] /api/auth/signin/apple
    12:11:10:97
    2021-09-06T09:11:11.039Z    94ed517b-eb40-4c92-bb09-461801bb5c62    DEBUG   GET_AUTHORIZATION_URL [
      'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&id_token&response_mode=form_post&scope=name%20email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%*my_url*%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fapple&client_id=my_client'
    ]



import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
import { API } from "../../../services/API";

const callbacks = {
  ...
};

const providers = [
  Providers.Facebook({
    clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  }),

  Providers.Apple({
    clientId: process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.APPLE_KEY_SECRET,
  }),
];

export default NextAuth({
  jwt: {
    signingKey: process.env.JWT_SIGNING_PRIVATE_KEY,
  },
  callbacks,
  providers,
});
```

This is the page I am redirected every time I press continue button once I enter my credentials to apple login page.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to share your callback code ? looks like you are doing replace action there, for something which is null

Comment: @RGog What callback code? My private key is null, I checked the source code where the problem occurs and came out that it is because of private key which is null. Somehow vercel doesn't return the set private key correctly

Comment: i was referring to `const callbacks = {...};`. So, It is resolved now ? then cool !

Comment: @RGog it is not yet, I spend way too much time on this problem so I started doing other stuff, I just know that it is a problem with private key. The callback code is unimportant, nothing important there

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was a problem with nextauth since I even found one example, the guy used next-auth, as well, and had apple signin and I tried it and it failed and I thought it was a problem with next-auth. BUT the problem was with my .env vars I didn't add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to my next.js app .env variables.

I read about it but it didn't say that it is required so I thought it was unimportant.